# How do I get the total combinations of 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I am a SQL Newbie and haven't been able to find my answer after hours of searching.

[image: Sales Order table]

I have the above table where I want to see a transposed list of articles that belong to an order number. My file has over 900k rows and over 37k articles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The keyword you want to search for is "pivot".

Comment: TSQL doesn't have dynamic pivot.  Sounds more like STRING_AGG or FOR JSON.

Comment: ^But you can emulate [dynamic pivoting with Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/). 

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! How, exactly, do you plan to read such a transposed list?